# Aws Lambda multiple concurrencies from 1 eventbridge timer

Tags: aws-lambda, concurrency, aws-event-bridge

Good afternoon,

I have an aws eventbridge timer that triggers an aws lambda every 15 minutes. The lambda takes at most 30 seconds to execute, doesn't go over memory allotment, has a 5 minute timeout, is set for zero retries, has 100% success over the past several hours.

However aws is still running at least 8 and up to 36 instances of this lambda concurrently. I have no idea what is triggering these additional concurrencies. Nothing is outlined in the cloudwatch logs, the eventbridge timer is saying it only triggers once.

Where can I find out what/why these additional instances are getting triggered concurrently?

Comment: Did you try logging the lambda event? Often there is information on what triggered it.

Comment: I had not. will give that a go

Answer (score 1):

I had overlooked that I had a double definition for the event to fire in my cdk stack. Copy and paste error from the example docs. DOH

```
Rule rule = new Rule(this, this.Node.TryGetContext("eventName").ToString(), new RuleProps
            {
                Enabled = false,
                //bad pattern
                //EventPattern = new EventPattern
                //{
                //    Source = new[] { "aws.ec2" }
                //},
                Schedule = Schedule.Rate(Duration.Minutes(15)),
                RuleName = this.Node.TryGetContext("eventName").ToString()
            }) ;
```

Comment: Hi, what was the double definition? It would be useful for me to simulate provisioned concurrency

Comment: the event pattern and the schedule. If you are looking for firing off multiple for testing, then you could adjust the schedule rate to something like a second. As long as your lambda code executes for longer than the schedule rate, anyway.

Could also put the lambda behind an apigateway and blast away at it with an automated postman run